# How do I open a directory at kernel level using the file descriptor for that directory?

Tags: c, file-io, filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on a project where I must open a directory and read the files/directories inside at kernel level. I'm basically trying to find out how `ls` is implemented at kernel level.

Right now I've figured out how to get a file descriptor for a directory using `sys_open()` and the `O_DIRECTORY flag`, but I don't know how to read the fd that I receive. If anyone has any tips or other suggestions I'd appreciate it. (Keep in mind this has to be done at kernel level).

**Edit:For a long story short, For a school project I am implementing file/directory attributes. Where I'm storring the attributes is a hidden folder at the same level  of the file with a given attribute. (So a file in Desktop/MyFolder has an attributes folder called Desktop/MyFolder/.filename_attr). Trust me I don't care to mess around in kernel for funsies. But the reason I need to read a dir at kernel level is because it's apart of project specs.**

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that? It is considered *bad taste*. Why can't you have helper *user-land* programs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to caf's answer mentioning [`vfs_readdir()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/fs/readdir.c#L23), reading and writing to files from within the kernel is is considered unsafe (except for `/proc`, which acts as an interface to internal data structures in the kernel.)

The reasons are well described in [this linuxjournal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110?page=0,1), although they also provide a hack to access files. I don't think their method could be easily modified to work for directories. A more correct approach is accessing the kernel's filesystem [inode](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/include/linux/fs.h#L738) entries, which is what `vfs_readdir` does.

> Inodes are filesystem objects such as regular files, directories, FIFOs and other
>   beasts.  They live either on the disc (for block device filesystems)
>   or in the memory (for pseudo filesystems).

Notice that `vfs_readdir()` expects a `file *` parameter. To obtain a `file` structure pointer from a user space file descriptor, you should utilize the kernel's file descriptor table.

The [kernel.org files documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/files.txt) says the following on doing so safely:

> To look up the file structure given an fd, a reader
>      must use either `fcheck()` or `fcheck_files()` APIs. These
>      take care of barrier requirements due to lock-free lookup.
>      An example :

```
    rcu_read_lock();
    file = fcheck_files(files, fd);
    if (file) {
        // Handling of the file structures is special. 
        // Since the look-up of the fd (fget() / fget_light()) 
        // are lock-free, it is possible that look-up may race with 
        // the last put() operation on the file structure. 
        // This is avoided using atomic_long_inc_not_zero() on ->f_count
        if (atomic_long_inc_not_zero(&file->f_count))
            *fput_needed = 1;
        else
        /* Didn't get the reference, someone's freed */
            file = NULL;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    ....
    return file;
```

> `atomic_long_inc_not_zero()` detects if `refcounts` is already zero or 
>   goes to zero during increment. If it does, we fail `fget()` / `fget_light()`.

Finally, take a look at [`filldir_t`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/include/linux/fs.h#L1526), the second parameter type.

Comment: Great user-mode solution, but probably not useful in a kernel module.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I definitely read through the question too quickly. Better? :)

Comment: Yep.  Learned a bunch about Linux file handling.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `vfs_readdir()` from [`fs/readdir.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/fs/readdir.c).

In general though kernel code does not read directories, user code does.