# Read a device from kernel module similar to "ls" command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to read a device from kernel module.
The output should be similer to output of "ls" command

My read function is:

```
static void read_file(char *filename)
{
  struct file *fd;
  char buf[1];
  unsigned long long offset=0;
  mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
  set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

  fd = filp_open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
  if (fd >= 0) {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG);
    while (vfs_read(fd, buf, 1,&offset) == 1)
      {

    if((0 <= buf[0]) && (buf[0] <=255))
      printk("%c", buf[0]);
      } 
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Loop Ran\n");
    filp_close(fd,NULL);
  }

  set_fs(old_fs);
}
```

but it is giving output along with many garbage values.
I am having a file named "file1" in my mount directory.

o/p is (it is having "lost+found" and "file1" in it, but with these garbage values)

```
[

  558.452235] 
[  558.452238] (\x02[&  \x01  \x05\x1dQ\x04S\x01,Q\x01
                                                      8\x02\x01
                                                               -\x06AN\x0ex\x7f
[  558.452308] 'J6pA{h<;
                        \x01
                            ,Q\x01*+,'\x1f\x04\x02\x04* + , 4\x07\x05\x04\x03 \x04 \x05 \x06 \x07 \x08   
[  558.455546]  

 \x0e \x0f \x10 \x11 \x12 \x13 \x14 \x15 \x16 \x17 \x18 \x19 \x1a \x1b \x1c \x1d \x1e \x1f   ! " # $ % & ' ( ) 

    \x01\x0f,Q,Q,QA\x04\x1dQCQCQ\x03\x020\x04\x04,Q,Q,Q\x01A0,Q,Q,Q\x02\x18CQCQCQ\x01Z\x02
                                         \x01\x02.\x02
                                                      \x02\x02..
                                                                \x14
    [  558.525090] \x02lost+found
                                 \x03\x05\x01file1

                                                  \x01\x02.\x02\x03\x02\x02..\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08   
    [  558.529810] 

    \x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&'()
    [  561.391843] (\x02[&  \x01  \x05,QS\x01,Q\x01
                                                   \x018\x02\x01
                                                                -\x06AN\x0ex\x7f
    [  561.391914] 'J6pA{h<;
                            \x01
                                ,Q\x01*+,'\x1f\x04\x02\x04* + , 4\x07\x05\x04\x07
    [  562.125651] Loop Ran
```

But I want output similar to that of "ls" command in bash.
which shows clean name of files and directory.
I have searched Google for it,but its not helping.please help.

Comment: You are trying to read the contents of a file, which has nothing to do with the output of `ls`. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @CL. I want to read the contents of a directory which happens to be the mount point of a device.For instance: /dev/loop0 is mounted on /mnt/crypt. So I want to read the contents of /mnt/crypt using a kernel module. As the mount can change anytime I think the approach should be reading the /dev/loop0 file.And I am not able to read it properly. So please help!

Comment: You are confusing block devices and file systems. And why do you need to do this in the kernel anyway?

Comment: @CL. Actually I want to read content of that block device, What should be my approach? I want to make a log of this content in periodic time, which functionality I will add later using a timer, and so I want to add this module in kernel.

Comment: The output of `ls` has nothing to do with block devices, it shows the contents of a file system. Making a log with timers does not require a kernel module.

Comment: @CL. yes I agree.  but by any means if I want to read a block device from kernel, how should I do that?. As I understand that "ls" is a bash command, which we cant use in kernel. Is it possible to have similar functionality by any means? and as you are saying ls has nothing to do with block devices, but I am using device mount directory only.

Comment: @ CL. I had observed once someone commenting on a post that, people try to solve a different problem here at SO. People do that very often.

Comment: @ Mahi Singh: So I guess this is more of a general interest question, then? I was afraid you were trying to solve a different problem in the wrong way. People often do that on this site.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to open a file in the kernel? 99.9999% of the time, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8347553/1401351

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110) why it is bad idea to read/write from Kernel space.